# Laravel moving Controller logic to a Model

Tags: php, laravel

I'm at a stage where I'm refactoring my code, and I've come across an interesting conundrum.

In my `ArticleController` I have a bog standard store method for storing an article in my articles database table.

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(StoreArticle $request)
{
    $article = new Article();

    $defauultPublished = "draft";
    $IntranetOnly = false;
    $isFeatured = false;

    $isFeatured = ($request->get('featuredArticle') == "1" ? true : false);
    $IntranetOnly = ($request->get('IntranetOnly') == "1" ? true : false);

    $article->title = $request->get('title');
    $article->slug = str_slug($request->get('title'));
    $article->author = $request->get('author');
    $article->category = $request->get('category');
    $article->excerpt = $request->get('excerpt');
    $article->content = clean($request->get('content'));
    $article->featuredImage = $request->get('featuredImage');
    $article->featuredVideo = $request->get('featuredVideo');
    $article->readingTime = $this->calculateReadTime($request);
    $article->featuredArticle = $isFeatured;
    $article->IntranetOnly = $IntranetOnly;
    $article->published = $defauultPublished;

    $article->save();

    $article->handleTags($request);

    return redirect('editable/news-and-updates')->with('success', 'Article has been added');
}
```

I also have a function for calculating read time:

```
/**
 * Calculate a rough reading time for an articles by counting the words present
 * These words are then divided by a given reading time and rounded to the nearest whole number
 * Reading time average is roughly 267 words per minute, so this also accounts for relatively slow readers
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return void
 */
public function calculateReadTime(Request $request)
{
    $readingSpeed = 200;

    $title = str_word_count(strip_tags($request->get('title')));
    $excerpt = str_word_count(strip_tags($request->get('excerpt')));
    $content = str_word_count(strip_tags($request->get('content')));

    $words = ($title + $excerpt + $content);

    $minutes = round($words / $readingSpeed);

    return $minutes . ' minute' . ($minutes == 1 ? '' : 's');
}
```

My question is should these methods be moved to the `Article` model?

Comment: This question is pretty open to opinions and probably belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controller should be as slim as possible. Following a resourceful approach (which you seem to be doing), the `store()` method in your `ArticleController` class should strive as much as possible to look like this:

```php
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function store(CreateArticleRequest $request)
    {
        $article = Article::create($request->validated());

        // Redirect with success message
    }
}
```

Here, your request data is validated in a form request class before it even reaches the controller method; and then an `Article` model instance is created from that validated data.

A couple of other notes…

Statements like `($data['featuredArticle'] == "1" ? true : false)` are overly verbose. You’re doing a condition check which will evaluate to `true` or `false`; you don’t need to manually return each value in a ternary operator. So this could be slimmed down to `$data['featuedArticle'] == '1'`. Furthermore, if you pass a value of `0` by default, then you could just get rid of the check entirely. If in your Blade template you put a hidden input before your checkbox:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="featuredArticle" value="0" />

<input type="checkbox" name="featuredArticle" value="1" />
```

Then `1` will be send if the checkbox is checked (as it overrides the hidden input’s value, or `0` sent if the checkbox isn’t checked).

Also, try to stick to Laravel conventions to make your life easier. If you use snake_case for your input names, then it just makes life easier matching them up to model attribute and table column names. So use `featured_article`, have an attribute in your model with the same name, which maps to a database column with the same name again. This allows you to do shorthand calls like `create()` (as per my controller example) and `update()`.

Finally, methods like calculating reading time definitely belong on your model. Models represent *something* in your application. It therefore follows that you can do *things* with your models. Calculating the time to read an *Article* model instance therefore lends itself to having a `calculateReadingTime()` method on the `Article` model.

A bit long-winded, but hopefully there should be some helpful pointers for you in the above. I’ve been working on Laravel projects for around five years now and have found that this approach and conventions is what works best.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller's `store` article is fine, because it fills your article instance based on request data. It could use some refactoring and you could encapsulate more logic into your `Article` (for example, assign `slug` field inside your `Article` model whenever title is changed and so on).

But the line `$article->handleTags($request);` is a suspect, because your model should never operate with requests - it will quickly polute your model code with very specialized dependencies that you don't want (what happens when you receive your tags from cache and don't have a request instance? What happens if other type of request contains tags differently? and so on). Your model shouldn't have knowledge about requests or other parts of your app. Your controller is connecting the dots between them, so make sure your `handleTags` takes some basic abstract types/structures as a parameter (for example, an array) and make sure your controller takes and transforms data from request accordingly before feeding it to your article.

As for your `calculateReadTime` dilemma, it should definitely be inside your model. Think about it this way - do you have everything you need to calculate read time of your article inside your `Article` model? The answer is yes, it's a property of an article object, doesn't matter if you store it in DB or calculate it off other properties. Make `getReadTime` method. You don't want a controller to compute something about your model because it will tie that logic to a specific place in your app which is bad (what happens when you need to calculate read time of an article in other controller? Other model? and so on).

Make sure you read about `has` and `is` concepts regarding object-oriented design, it will help you immensely.

Comment: So, essentially if I have what I need in the Model, that's fine... but if I'm having to drag extra items in, it's probably not a great idea? Also, do you think the store method is too bulky?

Comment: Yes, if you are dragging your `FormRequest` into your models then your models will have very specific code. You need to decouple it and keep it as abstract between your entities as possible, that will make for a better design and will keep your code dry. As for your `store` method you can improve it by using `$article->fill($request->only(...))` call for fields that you take directly from $request object with no additional filtering. Also lines like `$isFeatured = false;` are redundant because later on you override the value anyway with a ternary operator that will handle all cases.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should move those assignments to a Service Class. You could also go ahead and create a repository class. This would thus become your code structure:

Controller -> Service -> Repository -> Model.

Doing this `$article = new Article();` is bad. You will have a had time when writing a test for your controller store method.

I would suggest you do this:

Create a Service class, say ArticleService.php. Define a store method in it.

```
    ArticleService.php

    use Article;

    class ArticleService {

        protected $article;

        public function __construct(Article $article){
            $this->article = $article;
        }

        public function store(array $data){
            $defauultPublished = "draft";
            $IntranetOnly = false;
            $isFeatured = false;

            $isFeatured = ($data['featuredArticle'] == "1" ? true : false);
            $IntranetOnly = ($data['IntranetOnly'] == "1" ? true : false);
            $this->article->title = $data['title'];
            $this->article->slug = str_slug($data['title']);
            $this->article->author = $data['author'];
            $this->article->category = $data['category'];
            $this->article->excerpt = $data['excerpt'];
            $this->article->content = clean($data['content']);
            $this->article->featuredImage = $data['featuredImage'];
            $this->article->featuredVideo = $data['featuredVideo'];
            $this->article->readingTime = $data['reading_time'];
            $this->article->featuredArticle = $isFeatured;
            //Capital letter I? You should be consistent with your naming convention                
            $this->article->IntranetOnly = $IntranetOnly;
            $this->article->published = $defauultPublished;

            if($this->article->save()){
                $this->article->handleTags($request);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And your Controller now becomes:

```
    class ArticleController{

        protected $articleService;

        public function __construct(ArticleService $articleService){
            $this->articleService = $articleService;
        }

        public function store(Request $request){

            //Some Validation Logic
            $readingTime = $this->calculateReadTime($request)
            $data = array_merge(['reading_time' => $readTime], $request->all());
            return $this->articleService->store($request->all());
        }
    }
```

I also see that you are not validating the incoming Request. You should always do that because you can/should never trust your users to always provide/input the right data. It is your duty to force them to do that. e.g I as your user might decide to enter my name in your email field. If you don't validate that data, you will end up with wrong data.

There is also the issue of individually assigning your request parameter to their corresponding Model attribute. I decided to leave it that way so as not to overload you with information.

In summary, just take a look at the following resources for more insight.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart-intermediate
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation
In short, read up the whole Laravel documentation! Goodluck!

Comment: What benefit is a service class providing here? Service classes are, 90% of the time, just stuffing methods into another class for the sake of it. This seems to be one of those times.

Comment: @MartinBean ... I don't agree with your assertion. We are trying to decongest the Controller class as well as define functions that could be reused every and elsewhere. That's what Services classes are for.

Comment: Models in Laravel already have a `create()` method. Creating a service class for the model to chuck in a `store()` method is overkill and re-defining methods for no benefit.

Comment: Overkill for his use case, maybe but are Service classes good, Definitely!. Calling the Model in the controller is bad. What happens when his code base grows and he needs to share some queries/functionalities across his application?

Comment: Your methodology is the symfony way and while it is a fine methodology, it is not the way Laravel has designed their system. You can build a Laravel based site as if it was a symfony site (repositories and services), but then the question becomes - why not build your site on a symfony framework?

Comment: _Calling the Model in the controller is bad._ Why? Why is calling a method on a service class that calls a method on a model class any worse than just calling methods on a model class? I’ve worked on Laravel projects for over five years and can count on one hand the times I’ve created a “service” class. To me, they’re an anti-pattern. If you need a service class, you need to re-factor.